# REMOTE URL UPLOAD in Laravel 5

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to make a site to upload files in Laravel, but I  can't :( , If I use PHP without a framework, everything work, but with it (Laravel), I get ERRORS and that is a problem.

**This is my code:**

```
<form id="remote_upload" method="POST">
      @csrf 
      <input name="url" id="url" type="url" />
      <input name="upload" id="upload" type="submit" />
</form>
```

**My AJAX code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#remote_upload').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
     url: "{{ route('remote_upload') }}",
     method:"POST",
     data: new FormData(this),
     // IF WE HAVE ANY FUNCTION TO SET UPLOAD PROGRESS FOR REMOTE UPLOAD - PLEASE TELL ME :) 
     xhr: function() {
          var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
          if(myXhr.upload){
              myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandlerHome, false);
              myXhr.addEventListener("load", completeHandlerHome, false);
              myXhr.addEventListener("error", errorHandlerHome, false);
              myXhr.addEventListener("abort", abortHandlerHome, false);
          }
          return myXhr;
      },
     dataType:'JSON',
     contentType: false,
     cache: false,
     processData: false,
     // IF SUCCESS
     success:function(data)
     {
        $('.result').html(data.link);
     }
  });
 });

});
```

And this is my Controller:

```
protected function remote_upload(Request $request) {
        $file = file_get_contents($request->url_file);

        // UPLOAD FILE
        if (getValue('storage_type', 'disk') == 's3') {
            $path = Storage::disk('s3')->putFile('files', $file);
            $storage = 's3';
        } else {
            $path = Storage::putFile('files', $file);
            $storage = 'disk';
        }

        return response()->json([
            'link' => $path
        ]);
    }
```

I don't know if we have a package to upload files from URL in Laravel :)

> **Note**: About upload verification (Check if URL, If Have SSL ...), I will do that, but I hope you see me, how to add the upload progress, the real size of the file and its original name through the URL only, **Before upload it** :)

Thanks

Comment: What are the errors?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you get the correct data from your ajax FormData object you can simply do this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $imgLocation = Storage::disk('public')->put("imagename", $request->file('image'));

    ...
}
```

That would save the image locally to your laravel project you may need to edit it for amazon s3 but should be similiar.

If you want to upload an image through an url you could try to do following:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
      $url = $request->image;
      $contents = file_get_contents($url);
      $name = substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);
      Storage::disk('s3')->putFile($name, $contents);
      ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I mean, I want to upload files from URL - Not directly :)

Comment: $cpmtents ? what is it ?

Comment: @SaifManwill I mean `$contents`

Comment: Thanks, I will try now :)

Answer (score -1):

Simply you can use the `Storage` like this:

```
protected function remote_upload(Request $request) {
    $file = $request->url_file;

    // UPLOAD FILE
    if (getValue('storage_type', 'disk') == 's3') {
        $path = Storage::disk('s3')->putFile('files', $file);
        $storage = 's3';
    } else {
        $path = Storage::putFile('files', $file);
        $storage = 'disk';
    }

    return response()->json([
        'link' => $path
    ]);
}
```